# Need help replacing deprecated SqlMapClientFactoryBean

Tags: database, spring, spring-data, deprecated, ibatis

I need to replace this deprecated class that's used within a new Spring Boot project.

> SqlMapClientFactoryBean

After a some searching I couldn't find any easy way to replace this, but a I feel there must be a similar alternative?

Please see beans & XMLs:

Bean definition:

```
<bean id="clientMap" class="org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="datasource" />
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:/my/path/to/SqlMapConfig.xml" />
</bean>
```

SQLMapConfig.xml:

```
<sqlMapConfig>
   <settings cacheModelsEnabled="true"
             enhancementEnabled="true"
             lazyLoadingEnabled="false"
             maxRequests="32"
             maxSessions="10"
             maxTransactions="5"
             useStatementNamespaces="true"/>
   <sqlMap resource="path/to/config/ibatis/ibatis.xml"/>
</sqlMapConfig>
```

ibatis.xml:

```
<sqlMap namespace="abd.xyz.flow">
    <!-- Object-Index -->
    <resultMap id="objectIndexResult" class="abd.xyz.model.ObjectIndex">
        <result property="objectIndex" columnIndex="1" />
        <result property="idx1" columnIndex="2" />
        <result property="idx2" columnIndex="3" />
        <result property="idx3" columnIndex="4" />
        <result property="idx4" columnIndex="5" />      
    </resultMap>

    <select id="wflow.getObjectIndexById" resultMap="objectIndexResult">
        select * from om.object_index oi where oi.object_index = #objectIndex#
    </select>

    <!-- GPQ -->
    <resultMap id="detail" class="abc.xyz.model.SomeDetail">
        <result property="processId" column="PROCESS_ID" />
        <result property="processTypeDescr" column="PROCESS_TYPE_DESCR" />
        <result property="nextActionCd" column="NEXT_ACTION_CD" />
        <result property="idx9" column="IDX9" />
        <result property="idx17" column="IDX17" />
    </resultMap>

    <select id="flow.getDetails" resultMap="Detail">
        SELECT * FROM flow.detail
    </select>
</sqlMap>
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are right that the docs may not explain this so clearly. Take a look at the official [Spring Boot MyBatis Examples](https://github.com/mybatis/spring-boot-starter/tree/master/mybatis-spring-boot-samples). 
You don't need a class to replace the `SqlMapClientFactoryBean` with another class.

**Equivalent to replacing `datasource` in `SqlMapClientFactoryBean`:**

You should just have to declare your datasource in your Spring Boot `application.properties` [like so](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html):

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/test
spring.datasource.username=dbuser
spring.datasource.password=dbpass
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

**Equivalent to replacing `configLocation` in `SqlMapClientFactoryBean`:**

And then specify the [`mybatis-config.xml` location](https://github.com/mybatis/spring-boot-starter/blob/master/mybatis-spring-boot-samples/mybatis-spring-boot-sample-xml/src/main/resources/application.properties) in the `application.properties` file also:

```
mybatis.config-location=classpath:mybatis-config.xml
```

**The above concludes your question; i.e. the equivalent to the `SqlMapClientFactoryBean`.**

For the rest of your config migration, the [docs indicate](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/configuration.html#Handling_Enums) that the `mapper` XML item now replaces the old `sqlMap` in your XML and the `settings` [in your](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/configuration.html#settings) declared [config file](https://github.com/mybatis/spring-boot-starter/blob/master/mybatis-spring-boot-samples/mybatis-spring-boot-sample-xml/src/main/resources/mybatis-config.xml) should stay roughly the same.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give that a try!